# Get all cookies from responseheader and auth

Tags: vba, excel, cookies, xmlhttprequest, msxml

Trying to get all cookies from site

```
Const LoginPage = "https://my.brobizz.com/selfservice/login/?language=en"
Const PostPage = "https://my.brobizz.com/selfservice/api"
Const Accept = "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01"
Const Accept_Language = "ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3"
Const Accept_Encoding = "gzip, deflate, br"
Const X_Requested_With = "XMLHttpRequest"
Const Referer = "https://my.brobizz.com/selfservice/login/?language=en"
Const User_Agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0"
Const Content_Type = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"

    Sub test()    
            On Error Resume Next
            Dim oXMLHTTP As New MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP
            With oXMLHTTP

                .Open "GET", LoginPage, False
                .withCredentials True
                .Option(WinHttpRequestOption_EnableRedirects) = True
                AddStaticHeaders oXMLHTTP
                .send

                Headers$ = .getAllResponseHeaders()
                Cookie$ =.getResponseHeader("set-cookie")
                MsgBox Cookie$
             End With  
    End Sub

    Sub AddStaticHeaders(ByRef wHTTP As Object)
        On Error Resume Next
        With wHTTP
            .setRequestHeader "Accept", Accept
            .setRequestHeader "Accept-Language", Accept_Language
            .setRequestHeader "Accept-Encoding", Accept_Encoding
            .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", Content_Type
            .setRequestHeader "Connection", "keep-alive"
            .setRequestHeader "Referer", Referer
            .setRequestHeader "X-Requested-With", X_Requested_With
            .setRequestHeader "Origin", LoginPage
            .setRequestHeader "Cookie", "monsido=0; autologin=0"
            .setRequestHeader "Cookie", "monsido=0; autologin=0"
            .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", User_Agent
        End With
    End Sub


Private Sub GetCookieAttempt()
Dim objIE  As InternetExplorer
Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
objIE.Visible = False
objIE.Navigate LoginPage
While objIE.Busy
    DoEvents
Wend


GetCookie = objIE.Document.Cookie
MsgBox GetCookie

End Sub
```

But `getAllResponseHeaders` does not contains all cookies, `.getResponseHeader("set-cookie")` returns only `PHPSESSID=d4q1id1oif95l7vlfp69vjgjuj;`, but directly site and `GetCookieAttempt()` return much more cookies as `monsido` and `autologin`, how to get all cookies? and how to auth into this site?

Comment: The page you posted only returns one cookie that is `PHPSESSID`, maybe those `monsido`and `autologin` are only returned after you login?

Comment: No, without login geting monsido try run GetCookieAttempt()

Comment: I think those cookies are only shown after some javascript code runs, which is why you cannot access them via `MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP`. If you really need to get those cookies, you best bet is using the method you posted using `InternetExplorer`